# QGraphicsView/QGraphicsScene rendering question

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, rendering, qgraphicsview

I am using QGraphicsScene/QGraphicsView pair in my application.
I had subclassed them for my purpose. The code snippet that generate the pair is below:

```
itsScene = new QGraphicsScene;
itsView = new QGraphicsView;
itsView->setParent(itsCanvas);

itsView->setGeometry(20,20,1700,720);
itsView->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::black);
itsView->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
itsView->setScene(itsScene);
```

After adding some widgets into QGraphicsScene my application final UI snapshot is below:
[image: Application UI snapshot]

Here my question is why there is some free space above the picture? What may cause this?
I am using some negative coordinates for my widgets. Is it related with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The negative coordinates may be the cause. `QGraphicsScene` calculates its bounding rect from combining the bounds of all items in it.

If you know your scene bounds, call [`setSceneRect`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgraphicsscene.html#sceneRect-prop) to fix it down to a known rect. This way graphics items placed out of the bound will not cause the scene to expand beyond what you want.